# Telephone Exchange Vandalism

Tags: combinatorics

Our [telephone exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange) has 1000 wire-based connections. You dial a number, you get connected to the exchange and they put you through.

Yesterday, vandals broke in and disconnected all the wires. Your job is to reconnect them.

You can phone any number, and you get a conversation such as:

> Hello, is this 123456?
>   No, this is 654321.

Or maybe a positive result!

**How quickly can you restore our telephone exchange?**

Comment: What do you mean by "how quickly"? Minimum number of calls? Some other metric? This seems either "unclear what you're asking" or a pure textbook question.

Comment: how long will it take?

Comment: How long according to *what*? How long does a call take? How long does adding a wire take?

Comment: can you have the job done by the end of today? tomorrow? next week? blah blah blah. More seriously, how many calls will you need to make?

Comment: Is there anything that makes this *not* just a pure math problem, where the answer is "999 calls"?

Comment: it was never in my textbooks when I was at school